# How to capture screen video in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, screen, screen-recording

I want to capture video from screen.

I am unable to capture video from avplayer layer. But, can record from other viewes.

Do I need to search code for OpenGLES?

Comment: Don't forget to award the bounty by clicking the blue number below the acceptance tick!

Comment: please see my comment in the accepted answer... don't think it's the right one...

Answer (score 3):

You can have look at the [blog](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673).
I think it covers what you want.
Actually this blog does not use `AVPlayer`, but rather it uses `AVAssetWriter`.
Look into the comments there you can get hint using `AVPlayer`.

Or you can have this [project](https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen), which is for recording of screen.

Answer (score 3):

These two libraries are the best possible options that you can use to record video of your application screen.
`https://github.com/wess/Glimpse
https://everyplay.com/about`

Answer (score 2):

Yes I'm working with the same job it comes black screen because of high frameDuration of video .But I've solved this
Don't add AVPlayer to that view. Add to another view and note the time at play and then crop the video of time that has played and after all merge with the recorded video.
I've stated it shortly but I hope you will understand.

Comment: I can not do same as I have added two AVPlayer with different speed and zoom level and want to get recording for both at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on OpenGLES to render video layer, otherwise it will look black

Comment: But, my project is non OpenGLES, so how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the GPUImage framework, for a number of reasons:

1. It *IS* OpenGL but is wrapped in Objective-C, so there's no need to learn OpenGL to implement it
2. It is 100% App Store vetted - I have an app in the store that uses it now, as do dozens of others

There is a class named *GPUImageMovie* that wraps AVAssetReader for playback and another named *GPUImageMovieWriter* that allows you to write textures to file - these can be the same file, or separate.

There are quite a few examples available within the repository that should be pretty easy to understand...

Source Code / Git Repo
* https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Blog
* http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework

Hope that helps !

Comment: why am i downvoted ? because i commented on the accepted answer critically ?

Answer (score 0):

This is good for you testing you achieve that goal through this framework 
https://github.com/gabriel/CaptureRecord for screen capture. But, it can be used to record simulator only. You can't submit app to appstore using this code as it use private api.